# Windows 8 won't let me run vbscript even though I'm the admin

Tags: windows-8, permissions, vbscript

I wrote a little vbscript that downloads files from a web server. I understand why this would worry the OS but I am logged in as administrator and I want the script to run.

The exact error I get is

```
Error: Permission denied
Code:  800A0046
```

How can I tell Windows to let the admin do what he wants?

**EDIT**

I've put the download script below in case it helps. Tried it on a windows XP earlier it ran no problem. My home windows 8 is not letting it though.

```
HTTPDownload "http://site.com/fileA.dll", "C:\"
HTTPDownload "http://site.com/fileB.exe", "C:\"

Sub HTTPDownload( myURL, myPath )
    Dim i, objFile, objFSO, objHTTP, strFile, strMsg
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    If objFSO.FolderExists( myPath ) Then
        strFile = objFSO.BuildPath( myPath, Mid( myURL, InStrRev( myURL, "/" ) + 1 ) )
    ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists( Left( myPath, InStrRev( myPath, "\" ) - 1 ) ) Then
        strFile = myPath
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strFile, ForWriting, True )
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
    objHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
    objHTTP.Send
    For i = 1 To LenB( objHTTP.ResponseBody )
        objFile.Write Chr( AscB( MidB( objHTTP.ResponseBody, i, 1 ) ) )
    Next
    objFile.Close( )
End Sub
```

Comment: Please avoid the mask profanity its unwelcome here.  Can you post the script, while not a programming website, hard to tell the reason Winows is giving a permission error without knowing what the script itself does.

Comment: What directory are you trying to place the downloaded file in exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, it was originally C:\, tried in another dir and it went fine. Funny that Windows 8 won't let me download something directly to C:\ even with admin rights.

Comment: Windows works in similar to way Linux handles permissions.  A user might have read/write access to something but certain actions might require specific user interaction in order to execute the action.  For instance you can have a permission to do something in Linux but it might still require you to run the `sudo` command in order to execute the command.  In the case of Windows you have to escalate the permissions of the process ( user must grant it specifically ) in order to esclate the processes permissions to the user's permission level. The C directory is protected by default

Comment: You can either move/modify the script so it created the folder and file in a different directory to resolve the specific permission problem OR use the "run as administrator" which will esclate the process permissions to the user's permission level. This will then provide the process itself the ability to create the file just like you can create it using `windows explorer` ( which by default runs with the same permission as theuser ).  Don't compare Windows XP behavior to Windows XP, a TON of behavior, changed with the released of Windows Vista and the introducton of UAC ( for the better ).

Comment: Not being allowed to write to the root of the C: volume was a careful decision from Microsoft. To many applications (and scripts) used that rather then %appdata%. This way people get forced to correct their scripts rather then keep on using the old (pre NT era) solutions.

Answer (score -3):

Windows 8 by default disables the execution of all the scripts. It is done so that unwanted scripts are never run. It can be re-enabled to allow.

To do so:
01.Open Powershell in Admin mode.
02.Type : Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

This allows the execution of all scripts.

To Reset it:

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Undefined

More Info:
There are a total of 6 policies:

restricted [Default] : Only allows commands. No Scripts.

AllSigned : Allows Trusted (Signed) Scripts to run

RemoteSigned : Allows unsigned local scripts, but signed scripts from external sources

Unrestricted : Allows ALL scripts to run, but warnings are provided before running external scripts

Bypass : No Limits Whatsoever.

Undefined : Not deined in current scope.

For more Info, head over to:
[Execution Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847748.aspx)

Comment: This isn't the reason the script isn't working.  This is crystal clear based on the location of the script itself.

Comment: Not to mention that the script being run is VBScript and not powershell. Thus powershell security has no bearing.